# systemctl start all enabled, but inactive services

Tags: systemd

I am working on a configuration-as-code tool, and want to create systemd provider for it.

Now, suppose user describes in their configuration that they want `NetworkManager.service` enabled, and they want `cups.service` disabled.

We can (un)link corresponding unit files using `systemctl enable NetworkManager.service` and `systemctl disable cups.service` respectively, but now we need to stop services that need to be stopped and start services, that need to be started.

I was hoping that there is a command, that would do exactly that for me - "Stop everything that runs, but need to be stopped, and start everything that is stopped, but needs to run". `systemctl daemon-reload` is, unfortunately, not what I look for.

Is there such functionality built into `systemctl`, or will I have to manipulate every service individually?

**P.S.** This should actually be a separate question, *but* I suppose that there will be usecases, where my users will run my program from chrooted/containerized environment, where PID 1 is not systemd. Trying to invoke any unit manipulation actions leads to `systemctl` exiting with status 1 and message `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`. Is there a way I could check for such circumstances beforehand, or the best I can do is just trying and catching error?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question:

`daemon-reload` just tells `systemd` to re-read its configuration.

Note that *enabling* a service means that the service starts as a dependency of other units. Assuming your default target is multi-user, you could try `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`; in my understanding, it should start all enabled units that depend on *multi-user* and stop all others.

If this doesn't work, a simple shell script that uses the output of `systemctl list-units -t service` should do the trick. EDIT: `list-units` doesn't report enabled/disabled; you could use `systemctl status -t service \*` instead.

Finally, perhaps you actually want this:

```
systemctl enable --now SERVICE
systemctl disable --now SERVICE
```

`--now` starts/stops the service at the same time as en/disabling it. Of course, you can also `systemctl start SERVICE` and `systemctl stop SERVICE` separately.